# Copy to pasteboard file paths and urls on Snow Leopard or above

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, pasteboard

I want to copy file paths in clipboard so they can be copied in text editors as strings but I want them also available to Finder to copy files.

I've written the code shown below compliant with Snow Leopard guidelines (eg use writeObjects when copy file urls)

```
NSString* path1 = @"/Users/dave/trash/mas.sh";
NSString* path2 = @"/Users/dave/trash/books.xml";
NSURL* url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1 isDirectory:NO];
NSURL* url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2 isDirectory:NO];
NSArray* paths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1, path2, nil];

NSString* pathPerLine = [paths componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
// Put strings on top otherwise paster app receives the url (only the first)
// Urls will be used by Finder for files operations (copy, move)
NSArray* urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pathPerLine, url1, url2, nil];
NSPasteboard* pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard clearContents];
[pasteboard writeObjects:urls];
```

But on some editors (like XCode) also the urls are pasted as shown below (Finder uses correctly the urls to copy/move)

```
/Users/dave/trash/mas.sh
/Users/dave/trash/books.xml
file://localhost/Users/dave/trash/mas.sh
file://localhost/Users/dave/trash/books.xml
```

How can I paste only the file paths without the file URLs using 10.6 compliant code?

The [NSFilenamesPboardType](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) usage *seems* discouraged

> NSFilenamesPboardType
>       An array of NSString objects designating one or more filenames.
>       On Mac OS X v10.6 and later, use writeObjects: to write file URLs to the pasteboard.
>       Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.
>       Declared in NSPasteboard.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation can sound like you must only use `writeObjects:`, but you only use this for the file URLs.

At the bottom of NSPasteboard.h is this section:

```
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSStringPboardType;     // Use NSPasteboardTypeString
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSFilenamesPboardType;      // Use -writeObjects: to write file URLs to the pasteboard
```

These are the old types you shouldn't use but it shows that you only use `writeObjects:` when trying to put file URLs (or URLs). And use the types for other data.

So to get the correct behaviour:

```
NSString* path1 = @"/Users/dave/trash/mas.sh";
NSString* path2 = @"/Users/dave/trash/books.xml";
NSURL* url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1 isDirectory:NO];
NSURL* url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2 isDirectory:NO];
NSArray* paths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1, path2, nil];

NSString* pathPerLine = [paths componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

//Note, only the URLs not the pathsPerLine
NSArray* urls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url1, url2, nil];
NSPasteboard* pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard clearContents];
[pasteboard writeObjects:urls];
//Now add the pathsPerLine as a string
[pasteboard setString:pathPerLine forType:NSStringPboardType];
```

Comment: Under 10.8 only the first path is pasted and it is pasted with file:// prefixed protocol

Comment: Do you mean with this code or in Finder? I'm on 10.8 and both the code and Finder paste all filenames and dont have the file:// prefix.

Comment: I run your snippet (after fixing the error on last line pathsPerLine is pathPerLine) and when I paste on KomodoEdit I obtain ONLY one path (expected two) in this form file://localhost/Users/dave/trash/mas.sh, pasting on others apps like TextWranger works fine

Comment: Then it is a problem with komodo edit, it is obtained the URL instead of string, and not removing the file protocol as other apps do.